# Как на py считывать входные данные, состоящие из n строк, если не знаешь число n?

Tags: python, строки, input

Теоретически вроде никак, но условия задачи не я составлял, так что буду рад любым костылям. Пример входных данных:

```
surname,name,phone,test1,test2,test3,test4,extra,final,mark
Ivanov,Pavel,,23,36,,45,,47,
Kuznetsov,Ivan,,78,88,,77,,45,
Sidorov,Alexander,,90,80,,100,90,46,
Popov,Mike,,11,0,,4,,,2
Bobov,Oleg,,,20,,30,,40,
```

Comment: Вы либо условие в вопрос добавьте либо еще как-то вопрос поясните.

Comment: Условия нерелевантны. Смысл проблемы в том, что входные данные подаются строками, кол-во которых неизвестно.

Comment: Ваши входные данные нерелевантны. Хоть что и откуда считывается, напишите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Олимпиада ИТМО, знакомо)

Код для того, чтобы считать входные данные:

```py
content = []
while True:
    try:
        line = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    content.append(line)
```